# Make sure to insert and update row in database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, console-application, sqlcommand

A bit of pseudocode for you, the system itself is much more verbose:

```
using (var insertCmd = new SqlCommand("insert new row in database, selects the ID that was inserted", conn)) {
    using (var updateCmd = new SqlCommand("update the row with @data1 where id = @idOfInsert", conn)) {
        // Got a whole lot of inserts AND updates to process - those two has to be seperated in this system
        // I have to make sure all the data that has been readied earlier in the system are inserted

        // My MS sql server is known to throw timeout errors, no matter how long the SqlCommand.CommandTimeout is.
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
            if (i % 100 == 99) { // every 100th items
                // sleep for 10 seconds, so the sql server isn't locked while I do my work
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000 * 10); 
            }
            var id = insertCmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

            updateCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@data1", i);
            updateCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idOfInsert", id);

            updateCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

How would I make sure that the ExecuteScalar and ExecuteNonQuery are able to recover from exceptions? I have thought of using (I'M VERY SORRY) a goto and exceptions for flow control, such as this:

```
Restart:
    try {
        updateCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    } catch (SqlException) {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000 * 10); // sleep for 10 seconds
        goto Restart;
    }
```

Is there another way to do it, completely?

Comment: You could move all this logic into a stored procedure and schedule it as a job.  Then you don't have to worry about timeouts, etc.

Comment: Look at the C# documentation for try/catch/finally: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dszsf989.aspx

Comment: Regarding "another way to do it, completely?": I would insert all data into a temporary table and then perform the insert/update in a single statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of goto you can use a loop.

```
while(sqlQueryHasNotSucceeded)
{
    try
    {
        updateCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        sqlQueryHasNotSucceeded = false;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        LogError(e);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000 * 10);
    }
}
```

Comment: Confirmed you as answer - I'm still not completely sold, as we are still using try catch as flow control, which I don't like. But it does seem like it's needed in this case.

Comment: @Hejner Unfortunately there is no other way to catch a timeout exception or any other db exception that could occur.